# How can I abstract this CSS-style-changing function

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, parent-child, abstraction

I'm trying to abstract a function.

This function loops over every child node of a given DOM element (passed into the function as an argument)  and applies the same CSS style property & value to each one.

e.g.

```
function styleChildNodes(parent){

const children = parent.childNodes


for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

const child = children[i];




child.style.background = "red"


} }
```

In this example I have hard-coded the CSS property: **background** & its value as: **"red"** . The function will loop over every child node of the given parent element and change their CSS background properties to the color red.

But instead of having any hard-coded CSS property-value pair inside the function such as:

**background** = **"red"** , or,     **visibility** = **"hidden"**  , or,     **opacity** = **"1"** , etc.

I want to pass in the desired CSS property and its value as arguments.

Here is an illustration of the concept:

```
function styleChildNodes(parent, property, value){

const children = parent.childNodes



for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

const child = children[i];




child.style.property = value


} }
```

The CSS property and its value could be anything I choose and I could use the function like this :

`styleChildNodes(div, opacity, "0")`

`styleChildNodes(table, visibility, "hidden")`

`styleChildNodes(tr, background, "red")`

`styleChildNodes(div, height, "10px")`

These are just pseudo-coded examples - but hopefully it conveys what I'm trying to achieve.

Any ideas, work-arounds, or non-eval() solutions are welcome!

Thank you for reading :-)

P.S. I hope I'm not misapplying "to abstract" when I say "I'm trying to abstract a function." Please let me know if I'm using imprecise terminology!

*"Abstraction is a computer science concept in which an implementation is separated from its interface."*

Comment: The best practice should be to add a new class in JS in your function and add the properties in the CSS corresponding class. It's separation of concerns. (Furthermore warning, property added with style are style inline, is not the case when added with a class thus you could have specificity problems). In your case, if you want non hard-coded values thus you could use the cssStyleSheet interface. If you have a lot of rules you could add a dinamically created css link tag

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem -- applying inline styles like you do is going to get you into a lot of trouble because these override any stylesheet, and clutter your document and break the content-presentation separation. Ideally, inline styling should be outright prohibited for all but very niche use cases. Yours is definitely not such a use case. What your original problem probably needs is modifying some attribute of child (or their parent node, which his even better) nodes and let the stylesheet apply accordingly. I bet you don't really need all the inline style gymnastics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap property in brackets, but the property will need to be passed as a STRING so wrap it in quotes.

```
function styleChildNodes(parent, property, value) {
  const children = parent.childNodes
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    const child = children[i];
    child.style[property] = value
  }
}
```

you can also pass an object to do more than one:

```
function styleChildNodes(parent, styles) {
  const children = parent.childNodes
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    const child = children[i];
    child.style[property] = value
    for(style in styles){
        child.style[style] = styles[style]
   }
  }
}

styleChildNodes(parent, {
"color": "red",
"background-color": "green"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the stylesheet, I created a rule with the external properties in a class called `.yourClass` and added this rule to the stylesheet. After I have added this class to each node child (also deep node childes in my code). I created a possible call and use of this function. If you don't understand something please ask.

```js
let sheet = document.styleSheets[0]

function styleChildNodes(parent,...cssPropertiesValues){

let formattedCssPropertiesValues = cssPropertiesValues.map((item,index)=>
  index%2 ? `${item};` : `${item}: ` 
 );
 
let rule = `.yourClass { ${formattedCssPropertiesValues.join('')} }` //join convert from array to string. I'm using as separator the empty string to merge the items of the array

sheet.insertRule(rule,0); //the first parameter is a string (its format is `selector{prop1:val1;prop2:val2}`) that represents your rule. The second parameter is the position in the stylesheet where you insert the rule
console.log(rule)
const children = parent.querySelectorAll("*");

//When you have an iterable object like an array or an HTMLCollection
//you can iterate it whit a for of. `child` will be the current item
for (let child of children)
  child.classList.add('yourClass');

}

let parentNode = document.getElementById('my-parent');
styleChildNodes(parentNode,'opacity',0.5,'display','block');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet">

<div id="my-parent">
<span></span>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Umbert, thank you for responding! I will put your code onto my IDE and read through it carefully – admittedly it is slightly above my head as I am not familiar with methods such as .join, .insertRule and .map and I have never used the for-of loop so I will have to do a little research and learn some new things :-) !

Comment: @user13764383 I added some comment in the code that I hope will help you. If you think my answer solves your problem, please accept it with the check mark